# Python Pandas: Counting keys and summing up their values in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key-value

Data frame `df1` contains `key, value` pairs:

```
    key  val
0    1    7
1    2    5
2    2    5
3    3    4
4    3    4
5    3    4
```

How to get data frame `df2` that for each `key` has a record with two fields: `cnt` equal to the number of times given key is found in `df1` and `sum` equal to the sum of this key values ? Like this:

```
    cnt  key  sum
0    1    1    7
1    2    2   10
2    3    3   12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `agg` with a list of summary functions:

```
df.groupby('key').val.agg(["count", "sum"]).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: nice and efficient !